# Unable to Access and Connect to MySQL Server Data Base

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am totally new to MySQL Server but good at Java! I know how to connect with the MySQL Server using Java. Recently, I have made a simple small MySQL Server (Test) app for me. Its just for my knowledge! I have successfully connected to the database and successful to use INSERT and SELECT Statements in my Java App.

---

The problem is that my app is only running on my that laptop on which the SQL Server 2008R2 is installed on! I just checked my app on my another Laptop and it says the following error:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP 
 connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: 
 "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. 
 Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host 
 and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP 
 connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

I have tried this link so far no Success an still I can't access my Data Base on my other machine!

```
       msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx
```

---

From an answer i also tried my best!

```
          stackoverflow.com/a/12430561/2496503
```

From this answer i have come to know that my SQL Server Network Configuration(32-bit) is not showing any details/options as mentioned in the above answer here is a snapshot attached herewith !
[image]

PLEASE TELL ME IF IT IS ORDINARY THING THAT IT IS NOT SHOWING ANY OPTIONS! ELSE MY SQL SERVER ISN'T INSTALLED CORRECTLY PLEASE HELP ME GIVE ME JUST HINTS I WILL BE THANKFUL TO YOU !

Answer (score 0):

Perform these Steps for TCP/IP network Configuration upto step 6, ur problem will be solved.

[http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/articles/solve-sql-server-connection-problem.jsp][1]